# Public holidays that fall on a sunday

Tags: sql, sql-server

I dont know about other countries but in South Africa we have a public holiday on a Monday if the Sunday was a Public holiday. I need to write an Update statement that will return the date after x number of days and should the date be a monday after a public holiday it should add an additional day. My simple update statement looks like:

```
UPDATE tbl_ProjectTracker
set Predicted_Date =  DATEADD(DAY, 20, Actual_Eng_Start_date)
```

I already have a table for referencing but I am not sure if I should determine the additional day on the table or on the Update statement.
Please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a `PublicHoliday` table
Then you could Update predicted_date like that

```
DECLARE @PublicHoliday AS TABLE 
(
   HolidayDate date
)

DECLARE @NumberDaysPredict int = 20

UPDATE pt
set pt.Predicted_Date =  DATEADD(DAY, @NumberDaysPredict + hl.NumberHolidaysOnSunday, pt.Actual_Eng_Start_date)
FROM tbl_ProjectTracker pt
CROSS APPLY
(
   SELECT Count(*) AS NumberHolidaysOnSunday
   FROM @PublicHoliday ph 
   WHERE ph.HolidayDate BETWEEN pt.Actual_Eng_Start_date AND  DATEADD(DAY, @NumberDaysPredict, Actual_Eng_Start_date)
   AND Datepart(dw,ph.HolidayDate) = 1 -- Sunday
) hl
```

Comment: I have two views derived from one calendar table. The first view is WorkingDays where i filtered out the public holidays and the second is the opposite, named it Public_Weekends. What I am trying to do is that the query must look up the date from `tbl_ProjectTracker`, find the date in the WorkingDays view, and add x number of days to the date and bring the new date from the calendar into the tbl_ProjectTracker table. If there is another way of doing it, please suggest it. Thanks

Comment: You could `cross apply` to WorkingDays and get n-th day `order by workingday asc`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be a case construct for the number of days:

```
UPDATE tbl_ProjectTracker
set Predicted_Date = DATEADD(
 DAY, 
 CASE WHEN Actual_Eng_Start_date IN 
   (select day from public_holidays where datepart(dw, day) = 1) THEN 21 ELSE 20 END, 
 Actual_Eng_Start_date)
```

Unfortunately SQL Server's date / time functions are weak to say the least. The result of `DATEPART(dw, ...)` depends on a setting (`DATEFIRST`), so the query is kind of unreliable. Always make sure the setting is correct when you run it. It has been requested to extend `DATEPART` such as to accept an optional parameter for `DATEFIRST` so you'd get a consistent query, but Microsoft has closed this as "unsolvable" (https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/432303/datepart-dw-date-should-allow-optional-date-first-Parameter).